# Java: Write to tempFile in Windows Temp Directory

Tags: java, windows, file, temp

I am trying to learn Java in few day. I trying to write content to temp file and save this file in temp folder in Windows (that's my task).
I find some solution, but not work for me :(
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-data-to-temporary-file-in-java/
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/create-temp-file.shtml

Some time, i get error on applet, another way is empty page and file is not created, anywhere.

Comment: I've posted it before, and I'll post it again: roseindia.net is a **notoriously** bad resource and many of the examples/articles on there are misleading at best and outright wrong in some cases. I suggest you refrain from taking any information from there.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Its also got some strange Javascript issues that cause my firefox to hang. Perhaps its just my browser but no other sites are causing it to hang.

Comment: @Златко Баретата "I am trying to learn Java in few day." chuckle "http://www.roseindia.net/java/.." *LOL* "Some time, i get error on applet.."  **ROTFL**.  Would you like me to give you the bad news *now*, or in a *few days*? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You mention an applet, these operate in a sandbox and will not have access to the local file system. That is why it is not working for you.

Here is another rose india link re [writing to a file from an applet](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/applet/WriteFile.shtml).

Comment: I trying this, but result is ... strange. This code write to project directory file {className}$*.class (something that), but i can't find file, who i can used it :S

Answer (score 1):

To extend Paul answer.

Using applets you will have to ask user for location, where the file can be stored.

This behavior prevent applet free access to used hard disk.

Comment: I writing at last, with self sertificate who i accepted in web page, but .. when i trying to start from my JS script - permission denied to write in java.io.tmpdir ?